# Edited: split an array to two based on even and odd elements

Tags: c++

I want to write this program to read the number of element and a list from the user, print two arrays one for even and one for odd numbers, and display the number of zeros in the first array.

I corrected the errors, now there is no error but the output is wrong. 
Here is the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

// Function prototypes
int count(const int list[],  int size, int & odd_num, int & even_num);
void split(const int list[], int size, int list_even[], int even_num, int list_odd[], int odd_num );
void print_list(int array[], int length);

int main()
{
  int size; // llength of the array, user input
  int zero_num; // number of zeros
  int even_num;
  int odd_num;
  int * list; // array to store the user inputs

  // Prompt and read number of elements from the user into the variable size
  cout << "Enter number of elements: ";
  cin >> size;

  // Create a new array of size length and assign it to variable list
  list = new int [size];

  // Prompt and read the elements from the user
  cout << "Enter list: "<<endl;
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++) 
    {
      cin>> list[i];
    }

  // Call function count and save its return value in variable num_zero
  zero_num = count(list,size,odd_num,even_num);

  // allocate an array for even numbers
  int * list_even;
  list_even = new int [even_num];

  // allocate an array for odd numbers
  int * list_odd;
  list_odd= new int [odd_num];

  //

  split(list, size, list_even, even_num, list_odd, odd_num);
  cout << "Even elements: ";
  print_list(list_even, even_num);
  cout<< endl;
  cout << "Odd elements: ";
  print_list(list_odd, odd_num); 
  cout << endl;


  // Delete the lists
  delete[]list;
  delete[]list_even;
  delete[]list_odd;


  return 0;
}

//functions

//function to count the odd and even numbers and th enumber od zeros
int count(const int list[],  int size, int & odd_num, int & even_num)

{
  int i(0); //while loop variable
  int even(0); // variable to count even numbers
  int odd (0); // variable to count odd numbers
  int zero(0); // variable to count zeros
  while (i<size)
     {
       if (list[i] == 0)
     {
       zero++;
     }
       else if (list[i]% 2 ==0)
     {
       even++;
     }
       else 
     {
       odd++;
     }
       i++;
     }
 return  zero;

}

// function to copy odd and even number to seperate arrays
void split(const int list[], int size, int list_even[], int even_num, int list_odd[], int odd_num )
{
  int j(0);
  int k(0);
  while (j<even_num && k<odd_num)
    {
      for (int i(0); i<size; i++)
    {
      if(list[i]%2 == 0)
        {
          list_even[j]= list[i];
          j++;
        }
      if(list[i]%2 == 1)
        {
          list_odd[k]= list[i];
          k++;
        }
    }
    }
}

// function to print an  array
void print_list(int array[], int length)
{
  cout << array << endl;
}
```

here is the example of inputs and outputs:

```
Enter number of elements: 6
Enter list: 
1
2
3
4
5
6
Even elements: 0x988030

Odd elements: 0x7f601e480010
```

Comment: You could greatly simplify part of the problem by using standard library containers and [`std::partition_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy).

Comment: remove the void and brackets in void split(list[], size, list_even[], even_num, list_odd[], odd_num);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `split` in this way:

```
void split(list[], size, list_even[], even_num, list_odd[], odd_num);
```

It's wrong. It's function declaring. It should be (and two following lines has this problem too)

```
split(list, size, list_even, even_num, list_odd, odd_num);
```

The other problem is, you're printing `void` by `cout`, remove those `cout` codes:

```
split(list, size, list_even, even_num, list_odd, odd_num);
print_list(list_even, even_num);
print_list(list_odd, odd_num);
```

Finally, to print a array `int x[]`, you should iterator over items by a loop, so this code is wrong:

```
void print_list(int array[], int length)
{
    cout << "Even elements: " << array[] << endl;
}
```

Use this instead:

```
void print_list(int array[], int length)
{
    cout << "Even elements: " << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
    cout << array[i] << " ";
}
```

[Here is a working code (at least it compiles)](http://codepad.org/lNrzsDGX)!

---

While you have `std::vector` forget those hard arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `void` infront if your call to split on line 58. Remove the word void there.

Comment: thank you, I did it ans it solved the error problem, now the output is not right. I edited the question so it reflects the new problem. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Remove void in the function call

```
void split(list[], size, list_even[], even_num, list_odd[], odd_num);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use standard containers and algorithms:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    std::size_t count;

    std::cout << "Enter the number of elements:  ";
    std::cin >> count;

    while (numbers.size() < count)
    {
        int i;
        if (std::cin >> i)
        {
            numbers.push_back(i);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cin.clear();
        }
    }

    std::vector<int> evens, odds;
    std::partition_copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::back_inserter(evens), std::back_inserter(odds), [](int i)
    {
        return 0 == i % 2;
    });

    std::size_t numZeros = std::count(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0);

    std::cout << "Evens (" << evens.size() << "):  ";
    std::copy(evens.begin(), evens.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Odds (" << odds.size() << "):  ";
    std::copy(odds.begin(), odds.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is the instructor were clear about not using anything but this... I hate it but I have to follow the instruction. So I cannot use vector. Thanks

Comment: @user2841098 What is the purpose of the assignment?  Are you learning about memory management, algorithms, or simple C++ syntax?  If he is trying to teach you proper memory management, you can always write your own (simple) class that mimics a vector and use the rest of the C++ algorithms.

Comment: And have you been taught about templates and classes yet?

Comment: In that case, just keep this in mind for the future.  Much of what you are forced to do in academia is poor practice in the real world.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41066/discussion-between-user2841098-and-zac-howland)